# Initializing class object

Tags: java, class, constructor, initialization

I am new to Java. I apologize if I ask a simple thing.
I wrote the below code but it seems that it doesn't initialize properly. because when I print the size of list1 it show the size = 0!! However, it should be 4!

```
public static class MyClass{
        public List <Integer> list1

        // Class Constructor
        public MyClass(int n){          
            list1 = new ArrayList <Integer> (n);
            System.out.println("Size = " + list1.size() ); 
                    // prints Size = 0 !!!why???
        }

        public void init(int n){ 
            for(int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < list1.size(); cnt1++){
            list1.set(cnt1 , cnt1);
            }
        }
        ...}



public static List<Integer> Func1(int n){
        MyClass = new myclass (n); 
        myclass.init(n);
        ... }


public static void main(String args[]){
        int n = 4;
        result = Func1 (n);
        ...}
```

Why the size of the list1 is 0? It should be 4, because I pass 4 to Func1, and then it creates MyClass object with size n.
I would be thankful if someone can help me about this problem.

Comment: You misunderstand capacity and size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array lists in Java have both a *size* and a *capacity*.

- Size tells you how many items are there in the list, while
- Capacity tells you how many items the list can hold before it needs to resize.

When you call `ArrayList(int)` constructor, you set the capacity, not the size, of the newly created array list. That is why you see zero printed out when you get the size.

Having a capacity of 4 means that you can add four integers to the list without triggering a resize, yet the list has zero elements until you start adding some data to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the [`ArrayList` constructor that determines its initial capacity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29), not its initial size.  The list has a capacity of 4, but nothing has been added yet, so its size is still 0.

Quoting from the linked Javadocs:

> Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

Also, don't use `set` to add to the list.  That method [replaces an element that is already there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29).  You must [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) to the list first (or use the other overloaded [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) method).